# Pigeonhole Principle for sets

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I have been asked to answer the following question;

Let A = {2,3, ..., 50}, that is A is the set of positive integers greater than 1 and less than 51. Determine the smallest number $x$ such that every subset of A having $x$ elements contains at least two integers that have a common divisor greater than 1, and justify your answer.

My attempt at the solution is by defining a set;
$$S=[s\in A |s\in primes]$$
This defines the set containing 15 integers with no 2 primes containing a common divisor greater than one divisible by 1 and themselves. Thus, $x>15.$
Now I thought of taking;
$$P=[p|p\in primes]$$
And then continue by partitioning this set into 15 subsets. But I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is 16: to show that 15 is possible, just take $2,3,5,7,\ldots,47$.

Now for the fun part, making the pigeonholes. The first pigeonhole is $$S_1=\{2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$$
and the second is $$S_2=\{3,9,15,\ldots\}$$
Continuing thus, the $i$th set is (for $i>1$)
$$S_i=\{p_i,\ldots\}$$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime, and the elements that occur in the set are multiples of $p_i$ which don't occur in previous sets.

Note that every positive integer ends up in one of these sets; in particular, the numbers 2-50 end up in the first 15 of these sets. Thus taking $16$ numbers guarantees two in the same set (by PHP) and we're done, since any two numbers in a set trivially share a factor.

Comment: Doesn't the set of 25 integers you've given as an example contain elements that have a common divisor greater than 1? As 26 and 50 share 2 as a common divisor, so the example you've given for 25 wouldn't be possible, would it?

Comment: @JoshieBread Both 26,50 (since even) are in first set $S_1.$

Answer (score 0):

Your set S contains 15 elements.

These 15 elements can be mapped to 15 classes C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub>, C<sub>5</sub>,... C<sub>47</sub>, with each class C<sub>i</sub> containing all the elements in S which are divisible by i.

Every number in S can be decomposed to its unique prime factorisation, and we can form our classes. Note that the classes here need not be (and are not) mutually exclusive.

C<sub>2</sub> would contain 2, 4, 6, ..., 48.
C<sub>3</sub> would contain 3, 6, 9, ..., 48.

I would satisfy the condition of having a common divisor more than one if I have two elements k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub> from the same class C<sub>j</sub>for some prime number j.

Say I pick 3 and 6, both of these numbers are elements of C<sub>3</sub>. I have a common divisor of 3 > 1.

Since there are 15 class (pigeonholes) and we want two elements from the same class, then we need 15 + 1 = 16 elements from S.